# Como poner un div que tenga un background de una sentencia en Blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, div, background

Tengo este código:

```
<div class="w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
   <!--RELLENO-->
</div>
```

y quiero que el `div` tenga un `background-image` de esta sentencia en `Blade`:
`{{asset('storage').'/'.$servicio->Logo}}`.

No puedo ponérsela en la hoja de estilos ya que como mando a traer la imagen de la base de datos, hay muchas imágenes diferentes.

¿Cómo puedo hace para implementársela al div?

Comment: Metiendolo dentro del class ??? Se puede eso ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné, puse una etiqueta de estilos en la vista de esta forma:

```
<style>
    .logo_img{
        background-image: url("{{asset('storage').'/'.$servicio->Logo}}");
        background-repeat: no-repeat; 
        background-size: cover;
    }
</style>
```

y el div de esta forma:

```
<div class="logo_img w-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
       
</div>
```

y así ya queda listo.

Comment: Correcto, y recuerda que para que sea aplicado sobre el resto, es mejor que la clase tuya vaya al final. En caso de que se sobreescriba por alguna otra clase.